# How to compare two lists in python with the if loc condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, listview

I have two lists and i need to compare those two lists in below manner

```
import sys
name_1=['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','','Karun','mari']

list_match = []
counter = 0
for i in name_2:  
    try: 
        if i in name_1:
            pass
        else:
            list_match.append(i)
            counter = counter + 1

            print(f"'{list_match[0]}' is missing")
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    if counter > 0:
        sys.exit()
```

Output Getting:

```
   unnamed :3 is missing
```

Expected Output:

```
   Nani is extra column
```

Comment: you are never adding anything to `list_match`

Comment: I have added the changes

Comment: you need to iterate over the larger list, i.e. replace name_2 with name_1 and name_1 with name_2 in your example

Answer (score 3):

first thing, you miss an equal and plus there's a void space in between two elements of the second list.
Secondly, based on your script, you'll never get the expected output.
That's because "Nani" is only in the first list and not in the second but, since you're iterating over the second list, you'll never get to know that Nani is only in name_1.
If the task is to detect missing elements in the second list, but present in the first, you need to iterate over name_1, as it follows (I used the same style as you):

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun', 'mari']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','Karun']

list_match = []
non_match = []
for i in name_1:
    try: 
        if i not in name_2:
            non_match.append(i)
            print(f"'{i}' is missing")
            break
        else:
            list_match.append(i)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The program ends when it first detect a missing element. To terminate the program after every evaluation of the missing elements, comment the break instruction.
I didn't quite understand the presence of the variabile non_match, and the list_match presence, as well, since you didn't use them. I also replaced the last "if statement" with a "break" in the first "if statement".

A simpler way to get missing elements it's to consider the two lists as sets and get the difference between them, as it follows:

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun', 'mari']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','Karun']

name_1 = set(name_1)
name_2 = set(name_2)

print("missing elements in the second list:\n", list(name_1 - name_2))
```

if you invert the order of the subtraction you'll obtain the missing elements of the first list.

if the task is to obtain the elements that are missing in both list, you can try this:

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun', 'mari']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','Karun', 'Aldo']

name_1 = set(name_1)
name_2 = set(name_2)

print("mismatched elements:\n", list(name_1.symmetric_difference(name_2)))
```

**EDIT**
Based on the new request, here's the code:

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','','Karun','mari']

list_match = []

i = 0
while i < len(name_2):
    if not name_2[i]:
        print("empty element founded in position ", i)
    elif name_2[i] not in name_1:
        print(f"'{name_2[i]}' is extra column in position ", i)
        #break
    else:
        list_match.append(i)
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
empty element founded in position  2
'mari' is extra column in position  4
```

Remove the comment from break to end the program after the first mismatch.

**EDIT x2**
**RIEDITED**
if you want this kind of output:

```
nani  is missing in position  2
'mari' is extra column in position  4
'nani' is extra column in position  2
```

and if you NECESSARLY need to use lists you can try this (but I higly reccommend to use sets instead)

```
name_1=['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','','Karun','mari']

list_match = []

i = 0
while i < len(name_2):
    if not name_2[i]:
        print(name_1[i]," is missing in position ", i)
    elif name_2[i] not in name_1:
        print(f"'{name_2[i]}' is extra column in position ", i)
        #break
    else:
        list_match.append(name_2[i])
    i+=1

for el in name_1:
    if el not in list_match:
        print(f"'{el}' is extra column in position ", name_1.index(el))
```

**EDIT x3**

Try this

```
name_1 = ['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2 = ['mahesh','karthik','','Karun','mari']

i = 0
list_match = []
while i<len(name_2):
    if not name_2[i]:
        print(name_1[i], " is missing in position ", i)
    elif name_2[i] in name_1:
        list_match.append(name_2[i])
    i+=1

for el in name_1:
    if el not in list_match:
        print(el, " is extra column")
```

if the output you need is this one:

```
nani  is missing in position  2
nani  is extra column
```

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: can you please make the about statement work?

Comment: @user10389226 if the task is one of the above, it already works. You just need to copy the code you chose to use

Comment: can you edit the code which i have added on the top to satisfy the requirement

Comment: sorry, still its not satisfying the requriement. Can you check my code clearly and get that output Please

Comment: If it is null value i need to print which value is null and if extra column it need to print the extra column

Comment: @user10389226 tell me if that's what you needed

Comment: I need it exactly the output which i have give in my above code.. If we have missing column it need to print and if we have extra column then it should print that extra column.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort

Comment: @user10389226 you're welcome. I'm sorry if that wasn't what you needed but I didn't quite understand the output you need. You need to intercept blank elements in the second and mismatch in the first list? If you explain I'll try to help you. But you must specify from which list you need to know the missing columns (the first one? the second? both?)

Comment: I have a predefined file consider as name1 which has 3 records and other dynamic file which may contain n records. Now if run the code I need to print the extra record from name2. If it has any empty record let say at 2nd position I need to print name1's second position instead of empty.

Comment: edit X2 was almost correct instead of if not name_2[i] we need to keep something even if it has partial name in name_2 it will print name_1 instead of position which currently printing

Comment: @user10389226 go see the riedited version of edit x2 and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the symmetric difference between two lists then ideally you'd maintain them as sets but, assuming you have a good reason not quoted here to use lists then you can do it like this:

```py
import sys

name_1=['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2=['mahesh','karthik', 'Karun']

missing = set(name_1) ^ set(name_2)
print('\n'.join(f'{name} is missing' for name in missing))

if len(missing):
    sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate through the list you're wanting to check like so:

```
name_1=['mahesh','karthik','nani','Karun']
name_2 ['mahesh','karthik','Karun']

for item in name_1:
    if item not in name_2:
        print(f"{item} is missing.")
```

And if you'd like to add the items that are missing to a new list:

```
missing_items_list = []
for item in name_1:
    if item not in name_2:
        missing_items_list.append(item)
print(f"Missing items from list_2: {missing_items_list}")
```